# How can one get a list of the available functions in Lua(La)TeX

Tags: luatex, programming, lua

Is there a list or method to determine a list of the lua functions available/installed?

Sofar I could only find the lua source files.  Maybe I should write something that search through all the installed lua files for lines starting with "function".  Then I will have a list, but it would still not give me the rest of detail of the functions.

Any better ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You know the [LuaTeX functions short reference](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/old/functionref.pdf)? That together with the [Lua reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/) should cover all available functions if I am correct.

Comment: TNX I hoped that it was part of the installation I have. It will come to good use, I already printed it.

Comment: Unfortunately that first link is now dead.

Comment: @AndrewSwann fixed, although it is probably not  a permanent fix.

Comment: The first link dead again. (although if they say it's old perhaps you may want to add a disclaimer, as the new version may have changed) (perhaps make it a web.archive.org link so it's permanent)

Answer (score 6):

This is hard to answer, as you are asking the lua equivalent of 'what are the names of all defined macros?'. The answer is: it depends.

The core luatex functions are documented in the reference manual, as Patrick wrote in his answer. Everything else is loaded from lua source files on your hard-disk, but only if you (possibly indirectly) asked for it, just as would be the case for macros/packages.

If you are only interested in a list of defined lua functions in your current luatex source file, you can try this inside a lua code block:

```
function dump (prefix, a) 
  for i,v in pairs (a) do
    if type(v) == "table" then
      dump(prefix .. '.' .. i,v)
    elseif type(v) == "function" then
      print (prefix .. '.' .. i .. '()')
    end 
  end
end
dump('_G',_G)
```

but there are two caveats:

- you only get to know function names, not their calling conventions. This is about as useful as only knowing macro names (meaning: not very useful at all)
- circular references to tables will confuse this bit of lua code, it needs to be made smarter to allow for that

Comment: TNX also.  I was looking for info to extend the other answer I have received regarding a table of fonts.  The idea is if I know the function better I can maybe print a better table.